Looking to replicate this effect in blender
I'm coming from unity and this effect was achieved using a color ramp in luminance and a matcap. I've done a little playing around with the shader graph, but I really don't know what I'm doing. I do have a color ramp node setup with the same ramp I made in unity though. Anyone able to point me in the right direction?


Maybe put the Metallic value of the Principled BSDF at 1 and plug a Color Ramp in the Base Color, with an Input > Layer Weight node as factor:


That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you ^.^
